# Storing data in different Session variable with each form submit

Tags: php

not sure if this is possible with PHP, but was wondering if it is possible to store data in a different variable each time i submit a form.

I.e with the form

```
<select id="sampleSelect" name="sampleSelect">
<option value="val1">val1</option>
<option value="val2">val2</option>
</select>
```

I would select val1, POST it and store "val1" in a variable, then a 2nd time select val2, POST it and store "val2" in a different variable.

Not sure if this is possible with php, Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: You can access the posted data using the global $_POST variable. For instnace: $_POST['sampleSelect']; Just make sure your form's code is legit (form tag, method attribute)

Comment: And what exactly would the purpose of this be?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. for example you can generate random key name for session variable on each request. something like

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $_SESSION[ md5(unique()) ] = $_POST['inputName'];
}
```

or you can use ajax request and do the similar things with data attribute in your options tag(if you dont want session key to be random string). prevent form submit with `preventDefaul()` in your js, take value from `data` attribute from `this` option and use this value as key

```
$_SESSION['myDataAttrFromOption'] = $_POST['input'];
```

in this case every option has to have unique data attribute